# Parse pandas dataframe with column contain array

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data from csv file in pandas dataframe. One column contain array (I mean its JSON originally) who I need parse.

Example of one row:

```
ID_access,ID_part,ID_user,DATE,DESCRIBE,NOTE
865434334,66784,5468,2020-12-18 09:56:00,"Array
(
    [ar] => 0034
    [ident_a] => Array
        (
            [0] => tel
            [1] => sms
            [2] => email
        )

    [type] => G3
    [id] => 8573
    [parts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_sec] => 87322
                    [note] => Say hallo!
                    [date] => 2018-02-19
                )

        )

)
",""
```

How can I extract individual parts? Ideally, I need to add columns according to the individual parts of array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp, for example:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

rows = re.findall(r"(\d+),(\d+),(\d+).([-:\s\d]+).*?\[id_sec] => ([^\n]+)\s+\[note] => ([^\n]+)\s+\[date] => ([^\n]+)", t, re.S)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ['ID_access','ID_part','ID_user','DATE','id_sec','note','date'])
```

Result

```
   ID_access ID_part ID_user                 DATE id_sec        note        date
0  865434334   66784    5468  2020-12-18 09:56:00  87322  Say hallo!  2018-02-19
```